# Javascript - Append <script></script> to a Div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append a advertising script code into my div using Javascript. however, every example I have seen I've tried and doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Example:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('divname');

div.innerHTML += '<script type="text/javascript">
 atOptions = {
    'format' : 'iframe',
  'height' : 60,
  'width' : 468,
  'params' : {} };
     document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.testinghost.com/ads.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>';
```

```html
<div id="divname"></div>
```

Comment: This code doesn't append. It replaces.

Comment: just keep using div.innerHTML += instead of document.write

Comment: You're mixing `"` and `'`. Syntax highlighting helps you see what's messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're also trying to insert the `atOptions` object for your ad javascript to use?

The main areas where you were running into trouble was syntax errors in that object (I'm not sure whether you were attempting a multiline string?)  plus a document.write that may or may not have done anything (depending on when you executed your script).

Notable features of the below corrected example:

- Use document.createElement instead of creating the script tags with innerHTML -- this is not strictly necessary, innerHTML works,  but it lets you avoid having to do silly stuff like `'<scr'+'ipt>'`.
- You can use protocol-relative URLs instead of having to look up location.protocol.  `"//foo.com"` will use whichever protocol matches that used for the current page.   (But it would be better to [simply use https](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) when loading ad script, even if the current page is not using SSL, unless the ad script is not able to cope with that.)
- Condense your atOptions object into a single line, for easier insertion. (You could use [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in most modern browsers, but this is small enough that it's not really necessary.)

```js
var div = document.getElementById('divname');

var s1 = document.createElement('script');
s1.type = 'text/javascript';
s1.innerHTML = 'atOptions = {format: "iframe", height: 60, width: 468, params: {}};';

var s2 = document.createElement( 'script' );
s2.type = 'text/javascript';
s2.src = "//www.testinghost.com/ads.js";
div.appendChild( s1 );
div.appendChild( s2 ); 

// confirm it worked:
console.log(div.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="divname"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is cleaner:

```js
    var div = document.getElementById('divname');
    
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = 'https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1';

    // optinal options
    /*
    script.onload = () => {
        resolve();
    };
    script.onerror = () => {
        resolve();
    };
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true; */
    
    div.appendChild(script);
```

```html
<div id="divname"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : 'f3710ba7fe78163bb5a5cf86e9fbe7d5',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 300,
        'width' : 160,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://jennyunfit.com/f3710ba7fe78163bb5a5cf86e9fbe7d5/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = document.getElementById('divname');

div.innerHTML += '<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
    'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 60,
        'width' : 468,
        'params' : {} };
     document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.testinghost.com/ads.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>';
```

```html
<div id="divname"></div>
```

Comment: There's so much non-working stuff here. I'll try to clean it up, but there's only so much I can do. Please take the time to improve your post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = document.getElementById('divname');

div.innerHTML += '<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
    'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 60,
        'width' : 468,
        'params' : {} };
     document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.testinghost.com/ads.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>';
```

```html
<div id="divname"></div>
```